# How to get formatted LOGGER.warn result in java?

Tags: java, logging, format, log4j

I have several log messages in my class

```
     LOGGER.warn("Ignore [{}] preference for user [{}] with id = [{}], value =[{}])",
                            preference.getUserPreferenceType(),
                            userService.findById(preference.getUserId()).getUserName(),
                            preference.getUserPreferenceId(),
                            preference.getValue());
```

I need to put formatted message into map. But It should be formatted value. Thus all `{}` should be replaced with values.

How can I do this?

Comment: Put _what_ in a map?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis key - userName, value  list error messages

Comment: Cant you just use ``String.format``? Why use a map?

Comment: Generate the message separately, store it and log it.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis In my case I already have properly written error messages

Comment: @f1sh I just need store all formated error messages in collection

Comment: What library do you use for logging?

Comment: @Rae Burawes log4j

Comment: @f1sh String.format cannot work with {}

Comment: Go with org.slf4j.Logger and org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.

Comment: @gstackoverflow thats correct. You will have yo use ``String.replace`` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution:

```
 MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(oldFormatString, new Object[]{value1,value2...}).getMessage()
```

Comment: Log4j 1.x had end of life in August 2015

Comment: @Arne Burmeister there a lot of old projects in the world

Comment: Right, but you should give Slf4j wrapper a try

Comment: @Arne Burmeister I use in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this placeholders are replaced by the logging framework or the facade. Have a look at [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)/[Logback](http://logback.qos.ch), [Log4j 2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html) does similar. For performance reasons this is done inside logging. Otherwise you would have to check for the log level enabled to avoid possible costly `toString()` calls on concatenating (or formatting) log messages.

Only old style logging frameworks do not support this - do not use them any more if possible!

Answer (score 0):

As @f1sh suggested, I think you are looking for something like:

```
LOGGER.warn(String.format("First %d, Second %d, Third %d", var1, var2, var3));
```